# Get RSSI and Mac origin on a mesh network for probe request

Tags: cisco, mac-address

I'm working on a project of indoor localization based on wifi.
I believe we can get the RSSI and the MAC address from the frame header, however i would like to know if there is a way to get this infos from the root node in a mesh network.
So if a device is performing a probe request with a remote node, is the root node aware of it ?

To better understand, i know that cisco CMX can do that with a cisco MSE as a root node. Does anyone know how they do that ? Is there a way do to that in a open source way ?

Thanks !